# index of duplicates everywhere in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, extract

I know I can get the index of duplicates using `duplicated` in R. But I wonder how to get the index of all instances of a duplicate in the entire vector?

As a trivial example, if `1, 7` are duplicates, how to get the indices of theses values all over the vector?

```
a = c(1, 7, 5, 7, 4, 1)

duplicated(a)
```

## Desired output:

```
c(T, T, F, T, F, T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
duplicated(a) | duplicated(a, fromLast = TRUE)

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what the difference it made by adding `fromLast` argument?

Comment: @Daman deep `fromLast = TRUE` looks for duplicates from the opposite direction.  That is, from the last element of the vector to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `table`

```
(table(a) > 1)[as.character(a)]
```

---

Or using `ave`

```
ave(a, a, FUN = length) > 1
```